# Undertanding Sample Sizes in qqplots with R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot QQ graphs with the MASS Boston data set and comparing how the plots will change with increased random data points. I'm looking at the R documentation on [qqnorm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/qqnorm) but it doesn't seem to let me select an n value as a parameter? I'd like to plot the QQplots of “random” samples of size 10, 100, and 1000 samples all from a normal distribution for the same variable all in a 3x1 matrix.

Example would be if I wanted to look at the QQplot for Boston Crime, how would I get

```
qqnorm(Boston$crim) #find how to set n = 10
qqnorm(Boston$crim) #find how to set n = 100
qqnorm(Boston$crim) #find how to set n = 1000
```

Also if someone could elaborate when to use qqplot() vs qqnorm(), I'd appreciate it.

I'm inclined to believe that I should use qqplot() as such, as it does seem to give me the output I want, but I want to make sure that using rnorm(n) and then using that variable as a second argument is okay to do:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(1000)
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
qqplot(Boston$crim, x) 
qqplot(Boston$crim, y)
qqplot(Boston$crim, z)
```

Comment: When you make a qqplot for a set of values, the `n` needs to exactly match the number of observations you have. You can't change the `n` while keeping your actual observations the same. That doesn't quite make sense. The expected values of the plot depend on the total number of observed values. if you want random values, use `qqnorm(rnorm(n=10))` (but that of course changes every time you run it). Using `qqplot` with vectors of different lengths will perform linear interpolation of the shorter length to make it the same length of the longer (which is not ideal).

Comment: Your research question is not clear. A larger sample of random data will generate a smoother distribution. But that does not tell you anything about your data since it stays the same size and it is skewed right so it does not fit a normal distribution at all.

Comment: I think the point of the exercise to is to illustrate just that. With larger samples of random data, they scatter points of the QQplot will fit more closely with the qqline() function (yet to be added). I think its fine if the data changes each time it runs, so long as it highlights that. If that is the case, am I on the right track?

Comment: The data set only has 506 rows, how can you have `n = 1000`?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but to plot samples of a vector, define a vector `N` of sample sizes and loop through it. The `lapply` loop will sample from the vector, plot with the Q-Q line and return the `qqnorm` plot.

```
data(Boston, package = "MASS")

set.seed(2021)

N <- c(10, 100, nrow(Boston))
qq_list <- lapply(N, function(n){
  subtitle <- paste("Sample size:", n)
  i <- sample(nrow(Boston), n, replace = FALSE)
  qq <- qqnorm(Boston$crim[i], sub = subtitle)
  qqline(Boston$crim[i])
  qq
})
```